# Redirect to main activity after login

Tags: android

I want to redirect to my main activity after login.

when I put this code I get this error:

The method parseObssoCookie(String, String) is undefined for the type LoginActivity.Callback    LoginActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    LoginActivity webActivity;
    public static String loginCookie = null;
    private static CookieManager cookieManager;
    ProgressDialog progDailog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        webActivity = this;
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.LoginWebView);
        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Application",
                "please wait while page is loading..", true);
        // use cookies to remember a logged in status
        cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setCookie("set-cookie",null);
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();


        String url = "https://www.example.com/login.aspx"; //the web url
        loginCookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
        String obsso = parseObssoCookie(url, "ObSSOCookie");
        if ((loginCookie != null) && (obsso != null)
                && (!"loggedoutcontinue".equalsIgnoreCase(obsso))) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMainTabHolder.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }

    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {

        @override
        public void onpagestarted(webview view, string url, bitmap favicon) {
            // todo auto-generated method stub
            progdailog.dismiss();
            super.onpagestarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @override
        public boolean shouldoverrideurlloading(webview view, string url) {
            return super.shouldoverrideurlloading(view, url);
        }

        @override
        public void onpagefinished(webview view, string url) {
            // todo auto-generated method stub
            super.onpagefinished(view, url);
            logincookie = cookiemanager.getinstance().getcookie(url);
            if (logincookie != null) {
                string obsso = parseobssocookie(url, "obssocookie");
                if ((obsso != null)
                        && !("loggedoutcontinue".equalsignorecase(obsso))) {
                    finish();
                    intent intent = new intent(webactivity, activitymaintabholder.class);
                    startactivity(intent);
                        }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setCookie("set-cookie",null);
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Edit:

@Deepak : I did what you said but still it's not redirecting me to ActivityyMainTabHolder.class.
See my code below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    LoginActivity webActivity;
    public static String loginCookie = null;
    private static CookieManager cookieManager;
    ProgressDialog progDailog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.login);
     webActivity = this;
     webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.LoginWebView);
     progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Application",
                          "please wait while page is loading..", true);
     // use cookies to remember a logged in status
     cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
     cookieManager.setCookie("set-cookie",null);
             cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
     cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
     CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
     CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();


     String url = "https://www.example.com/login.aspx"; //the web url
     loginCookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
     String obsso = parseObssoCookie(url, "ObSSOCookie");
     if ((loginCookie != null) && (obsso != null)
          && (!"loggedoutcontinue".equalsIgnoreCase(obsso))) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(webActivity, ActivityMainTabHolder.class);
          startActivity(intent);
           finish();
     } else {
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
      webView.loadUrl(url);
     }

 }

    private String parseObssoCookie(String url, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {

  @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      progDailog.dismiss();
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                  loginCookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
      if (loginCookie != null) {
          String obsso = parseObssoCookie(url, "ObSSOCookie");
          if ((obsso != null)
                  && !("loggedoutcontinue".equalsIgnoreCase(obsso))) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(webActivity, ActivityMainTabHolder.class);
              startActivity(intent);
               finish();
          }
      }

  }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
  cookieManager.setCookie("set-cookie",null);
          cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
  cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
  CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
  CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
  super.onResume();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      finish();
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMainTabHolder.class);
      startActivity(intent);
```

replace with

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityMainTabHolder.class);
      startActivity(intent);
       finish();
```

Comment: Dear Deepak, I replaced but it doesn't redirect me to my ActivityMainTabHolder.class. it remains on same page after login. i have created this string  public String parseObssoCookie(String url, String string) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your method parseObssoCookie(...)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `parseObssoCookie(String, String)` method as **public** in  LoginActivity.java class

Comment: I have created this  public String parseObssoCookie(String url, String string) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 } but after login it doesn't redirect me to my app activity

Answer (score 0):

```
   finish();
     intent intent = new intent(webactivity, activitymaintabholder.class);
     startactivity(intent);
```

replace with

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(webactivity, ActivityMainTabHolder.class);
  startActivity(intent);
   finish();
```

Comment: Read my below comment. Thank U for all your Help.